# R shiny use input from textInput to be the column name in a tibble

Tags: r, shiny, tibble

I want to use the value from textInput to be the column name in the tibble I'm building. I tried to use `input$urgency1` as the column name but this creates an error. I tried replacing `=` with `<-` but it still doesn't work.

```
library(shiny)

ui <- fluidPage(
  textInput("urgency1", label = "Urgency 1", value = "2WW"),
  dataTableOutput("template")
)

server <- function(input, output, session) {
  output$template = renderDataTable({
    df=tibble(input$urgency1 = rep(1, 105))
    df
  }, options = list(pageLength = 10))
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One option to achieve your desired result is to make use of `rlang::sym(!!input$urgency1) := ...` like so:

Edit: As pointed out by @RonakShah in the comments there is no need for `rlang::sym`. `!!input$urgency1 := ...` is sufficient.

```r
library(shiny)
library(tibble)


ui <- fluidPage(
  textInput("urgency1", label = "Urgency 1", value = "2WW"),
  dataTableOutput("template")
)

server <- function(input, output, session) {
  output$template = renderDataTable({
    df = tibble(!!input$urgency1 := rep(1, 105))
    df
  }, options = list(pageLength = 10))
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
#> 
#> Listening on http://127.0.0.1:6488
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2021-05-18 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.0)</sup>

Comment: @RonakShah Hi Ronak. Thanks for pointing that out. Much appreciated. Best S.

Comment: Can you tell me what does "!!" do please? Does it mean to extract the string from input$urgency1? And what does ":=" do? I checked the tibble help file, it says use ":=" to create columns started with dot? But there's no dot in the column name?

Comment: Hi Subaru. Not easily explained. But I try. `!!` and `:=` are operators from the `rlang` package underlying `dplyr`, ... In you case `!!`(called bang-bang operator) converts the character `input$urgency1` to a variable name, i.e. after !! you get `tibble(2WW = ...)`. However, using `!!` requires to make use of `:=` instead of just `=` for the assignment. For more on this see ?rlang::`!!`.